# Reviews button not working in the jquery function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, web

I am developing a shopping website for food items. I have my products displayed on my order.php page based on an ajax call which will take the default category on my dropdown list. The items are displayed in cards each with a review button having class 'reviews'. However, when i am making a test with the button using jquery, the page is simply reloading with no action. Please help me

```
//order.php

<div id="message">
 </div>

 <div class="container" style="position:relative; top:200px; float:center">

 <div class="collapse" id="filterdiv">

 <form class="d-inline">
    <select id="Category">
        <option value='' selected>All</option>
        <?php 
        $fCategory="SELECT DISTINCT Food_Type from food";
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $res=$conn->query($fCategory);

        if($res->rowCount()>0)
        {
            while($row=$res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
                echo "<option value=".$conn->quote($row['Food_Type']).">".$row['Food_Type']." 
       </option>";
            }
        }

        ?>


    </select>

    <select id="price">
    <option value="">Price</option>
    <option value="lowtohigh">Low to High</option>
    <option value="hightolow">High to Low</option>
    <
    </select>
  </form> 
  </div>



  <div class="row" id="result">

   </div>
   </div>




<script type="text/javascript" src="Bootstrap4/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="Bootstrap4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!--Ajax code to get food info-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {

    $("#filterdiv").ready(function(){

        let foodType=$("#Category").val();
        let price=$("#price").val();

        $.ajax({
            url:'action.php',
            method:'post',
            data:{foodType:foodType,price:price},
            success:function(response)
            {
                $("#result").html(response);
            }
        });     
    });


    });

</script>   


   Now for action.php
   if (isset($_POST['foodType']) || isset($_POST['price']))
   {
    $foodType=$price=$priceSort=$foodSort="";

    if (isset($_POST['foodType']))
    {
        $foodType=$_POST['foodType'];
        if ($foodType=='')
        {
            $foodSort='';
        }
        else
        {
            $foodSort="WHERE Food_Type=".$conn->quote($foodType);
        }

    }

    if (isset($_POST['price']))
    {
        $price=$_POST['price'];

        if ($price=="lowtohigh")
        {
            $priceSort="ORDER BY `Food_Price(Rs)` ASC";
        }

        else if ($price=='hightolow')
        {
            $priceSort="ORDER BY `Food_Price(Rs)` DESC";
        }
        else
        {
            $priceSort="";
        }
      }

    $foodDisp="SELECT * FROM food ".$foodSort." ".$priceSort;
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $res=$conn->query($foodDisp);

    while($row=$res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {

        ?>

    <div class="col-lg-3 mx-0">
        <div class="card-deck" style="display:flex; flex:flex-wrap; padding:2px;">
            <div class="card bg-transparent p-2 h-100 border-secondary mx-0 mb-2" style="min- 
         height:35rem;max-height:35rem;">
            <img src="<?= 'foodImages/'.$row['Food_Url'] ?>" class="card-img-top img-fluid img- 
            responsive img-thumbnail" height="100" width="100%">
            <div class="card-body p-1 text-center">

                <h4 class="card-title text-center text-info"><?php echo $row['Food_Name']; ?>
                </h4>
                <h5 class="card-text text-center text-white"><?php echo $row['Food_Description']; 
            ?>
                </h5>
                <h5 class="card-text text-center text-danger"><?php echo "Rs 
               ".$row['Food_Price(Rs)']; ?>
                </h5>
                <button class="btn btn-success reviews">Reviews</button>
            </div>

                <div class="footer p-1">
                    <form action="" class="form-submit">
                    <input type="hidden" class="fid" value="<?php echo $row['Food_Id'] ;?>
                    ">

                    <input type="hidden" class="fname" value="<?php echo $row['Food_Name'] ;?>
                    ">

                    <input type="hidden" class="fprice" value="<?php echo $row['Food_Price(Rs)'] 
           ;?>
                    ">

                    <input type="hidden" class="fimage" value="<?php echo $row['Food_Url'] ;?>
                    ">

                    <input type="hidden" class="ftype" value="<?php echo $row['Food_Type'] ;?>
                    ">

                    <button class="btn btn-info btn-block addItemBtn">Add to cart</button>


                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



 <?php }
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried with `GET` request?

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco what difference does that make?

Comment: See if request what you receive is performed. Can you post a `var_dump($_POST)` after you make a request?

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco I tried the get. Still no action

Comment: Try to finish you statements with proper quotes for string variables: `$foodSort="WHERE Food_Type=".$conn->quote($foodType);` make it looks like that: `$foodSort='WHERE Food_Type="'.$conn->quote($foodType).'"';` because you search by `string`.

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco this works fine. I tested it before

Comment: Then make a `var_dump($_POST)` at the begging of your action script.

Comment: var_dump returns me an array of the query

Comment: Have you tried to execute you query with posted data in mysql?

Comment: @SergheiLeonencothe all the queries work fine. I've tested them individually. Problem is when I added jquery, that the issue happened.

Comment: Try to `var_dump($sql)` before to make a db execute.

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco as i told u, all the queries work fine, It is only when i have added all the jquery functions and making the links that it happened

Comment: Just make sure that at the end of all your adding you get the desired `sql` query `string`. This is simple.

Comment: Yesss. Resolve the jquery prob

Answer (score 0):

Change JS function:

```
$("form.d-inline select").on('change', function(){

        let foodType=$("#Category").val();
        let price=$("#price").val();

        $.ajax({
            url:'action.php',
            method:'post',
            data:{foodType:foodType,price:price},
            success:function(response)
            {
                $("#result").html(response);
            }
        });     
    });
```

Comment: That's not correct. Cause i want the producta to be displayed when on ready and on change both

Comment: You can add this chunk of code to your existing one, for handling both state (onchange and ready)